# Code review diff/merge tool

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, diff

When going through a code review session we use a diff/merge tool. Sometimes it is needed to **Go to definition** of a certain function that we examine.
Currently what we do is go to the file system or the development environment and open the file that contains the function definition.
It whould be nice to have the option to **Go to definition** right from the diff/merge tool (as you would from eclipse/visual studio). The expected result is that the file with the function definition from the same revision is opened.

The revision control software we use is Subversion with Tortoise SVN, and we try to find a diff/merge software to achieve this goal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following application: [Code compare](https://www.devart.com/codecompare)
It seems to integrate nicely into Visual Studio, and once in visual studio you can **Go to definition**.

After playing with it for a while I'm not sure if I'm satisfied with it.

The pros:

1. It fulfills the basic requirement of allowing the **Go to
   definition** functionality, and other Visual Studio's functions.
2. Very clear and nice user interface.

The cons:

1. Pretty slow in comparison to Beyond compare.
2. It doesn't show the difference in also another windows line over line. This is necessary when the screen resolution is low or the lines are too long.

Answer (score 0):

intellij diff is great why not do the code review with intellij free edition? you have there the option to navigate to source

Comment: Isn't this tool mainly for Java?

Comment: @noti yes mainly for `java` but supports additional languages and i've use it with (`python`, `javascrtipt`, `scala`) do you have any specific language you use? or a set of languages?

Comment: I intend to use it for C/C++.